# Control text direction for date input text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have textfield that I want to enter date in following pattern: `yyyy/MM/dd`
I have the input text direction rtl. When I start typing day then month then year,
I get the final displayed values as `dd/MM/yyyy` as in the attached image:

[image: User input]

I want to have rtl enabled and user can input day then month then year and the displayed final format will be `yyyy/MM/dd`

and final display should be like:

[image: Final display]

Please advise how to accomplish that.

Comment: But if your field has a `yyyy/MM/dd` label next to it won't users try to enter the date in that format?

Comment: Buddy, You will be confusing your users. How abt using datetimepicker instead or using 3 boxes instead of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling rtl does not help, since common digits have inherent left-to-right directionality and the slash is directionally neutral, so 10/12/2013 will be rendered left-to-right even if the general text directionality has been set to right-to-left.

If you want to display order differ from the actual input order, you need to add JavaScript that parses and reorders the input.

Answer (score 0):

Using RTL/LTR is not the solution. To achieve your goal, you must add a listener in tehe field to knnow when the user has finished introducing data, and then, as Jukka K. says, you must parse the introduced data with JS and show as you want.

If you need help with the JS code tell me.